# Fourier transform $u(s,k)=\frac{2\pi \delta(k-1)}{s(ik+s)}$

Tags: fourier-transform, transformation

Let's say I've given the following function
$$u(s,k)=\frac{2\pi \delta(k-1)}{s(ik+s)}$$
Where $\delta(k)$ is the Dirac delta function. I would like to find the inverse Fourier transformation of this one and normally I can easily do the calculations or look up a table or use Maple. But how can I be able to find the inverse by "hand" with respect to $k$?

Comment: If your integrating with respect to $k$, use the identity $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(k-1)\, f(k)\,dk=f(1)$

Comment: You are a lifesaver! I didn't know that this identity exists!